# Twitter OAuth Help

Tags: twitter, oauth, twitter-oauth, oauth-2.0

What variables do we need to store when we authenticate a user using twitter connect ?

Comment: Do you mean store for later authentication (already authorized users), or what values you need to include in the OAuth signature, during authorization?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `oauth_token` and `oauth_token_secret` that you get from the `/oauth/access_token` method is specific to the user and required to make future API requests. These do not expire but may be revoked at anytime.

Answer (score 2):

To make an API request, you only need the following list of variables:

- oauth_consumer_key
- oauth_nonce
- oauth_signature_method
- oauth_token
- oauth_timestamp
- oauth_version

and the API method-specific variables.

See this example: http://dev.twitter.com/pages/auth#auth-request

Comment: cool. let me be precise. what variables in these are dedicated to a particular user. like in facebook. faebook_id is needed to be stored against the user.